# Not able to retrieve data from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hi I need to get a List that is being returned by a stored procedure from DBContext. But I am getting the error below:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'VehicleFilterId' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation
```

Below is the Controller:

```
 [HttpGet("reportFilterValues/{vehicleId}/{vehicleName}")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> GetVehicleValues(string vehicleId, string vehicleName)
  {            
     var vehicleReportValues = -vehicleDataAccess.GetVehicleReportHelper(vehicleId, vehicleName);
     return Ok(vehicleReportValues);
  }
```

DataAccessLayer:

public class VehicleDataAccess : IVehicleDataAccess {

```
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
    public ReportDataAccess(IServiceProvider provider, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _provider = provider;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
    
      private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;       
      public async Task<List<VehicleFilter>> GetVehicleReportHelper(string vehicleId, string vehicleName)
        {
            int vehicleNumericId = 100;
            string vehicleTenant = "Kia";            
            
            using var scope = _provider.CreateScope();
            var dbContext = new DbContext(vehicleNumericId, vehicleTenant, _configuration);
            
            reportFilterValues = await dbContext.GetVehicleKeyValues(vehicleName, dbContext);                 
                        
            return reportFilterValues;
        }
    }
```

DbContext Class:
The SQL query in the class below works fine in SSMS. But its giving the error stated above here.

```
   public partial class VehicleDbContext : DbContext { 

 public virtual DbSet<ReportFilter> ReportFilters { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<VehicleFilter>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { vehicleFilterId = e.VehicleFilterId });
                entity.Property(e => e.VehicleId).HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
                entity.Property(e => e.VehicleFilterName).HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();
                entity.Property(e => e.VehicleFilterTitle).HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();
                entity.Property(e => e.SchemaEntityId).HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
                entity.Property(e => e.ModelTableColumn).HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();
                entity.Property(e => e.ModelTableColumn).HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();
                entity.Property(e => e.VehicleFilterType).HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicles>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { vehicleId = e.VehicleId });
                entity.Property(e => e.VehicleType).HasMaxLength(255);
                entity.Property(e => e.ParametersEnabled).HasColumnName("ParametersEnabled");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }


 public async Task<List<ReportFilter>> GetVehicleKeyValues(string vehicleName, VehicleDbContext vehicleDbContext)
 {                
    var sqlCommand = $"EXEC [CCAdmin].[spName] @vehicleName = '{VehicleName}'";
    var vehicleFilterValues = await vehicleDbContext.VehicleFilters.FromSqlRaw(sqlCommand).ToListAsync();
    return vehicleFilterValues;
 }      
}
```

Model:

```
[Table("VehicleFilters", Schema = "ABC")]
    public class VehicleFilter
    {
        public int VehicleFilterId { get; set; }

        public int VehicleId { get; set; }

        public string VehicleFilterName { get; set; }

        public string VehicletFilterTitle { get; set; }

        public int VehicleEntityId { get; set; }

        public string ModelTableName { get; set; }

        public string ModelTableColumn { get; set; }

        public string VehicleFilterType { get; set; }

        public VehicleFilter(VehicleFilterModel vehicleFilterModel)
        {
            VehicleFilterId = vehicleFilterModel.VehicleFilterId;
            VehicleId = vehicleFilterModel.VehicleId;
            VehicleFilterName = vehicleFilterModel.ReportFilterName;
            VehicleTitle = vehicleFilterModel.VehicleTitle;
            VehicleEntityId = vehicleFilterModel.VehicleEntityId;
            ModelTableName = vehicleFilterModel.ModelTableName;
            ModelTableColumn = vehicleFilterModel.ModelTableColumn;
            VehicleFilterType = vehicleFilterModel.VehicleFilterType;
        }    
        public ReportFilter()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

The

Can anyone please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share how the VehicleFilterId column is defined in the database?

Comment: The VehicleFilterId is PK, int, not null in the database.

Comment: Did you create a `public DbSet<VehicleFilter> VehicleFilters { get; set; }` inside of VehicleDbContext

Comment: Yes I have created it. Edited in the post.

Comment: i'd recommend double checking what is returned from the SP

Comment: The same query is working successfully in the SP.

Comment: You can try the given solution , hope it would resolved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`"I need to get a List that is being returned by a stored procedure from DBContext. But I am getting the error below:?"`***

System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'VehicleFilterId' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

> Yes its because you have define your `VehicleFilter class` with
> `VehicleFilterId`  and probably you are not returning this property
> from your `store procedure` as you might know when use `FromSqlRaw` in
> `EF` you must return the domain class `(VehicleFilters)` property
> value which is non nullable

***`Another problem is your syntax for interpolated string ($"") "var sqlCommand = $"EXEC [CCAdmin].[spName] @vehicleName = '{VehicleName}'" which is not correct`***

> As you might knwo while use `interpolated string ($"")` to pass
> parameter in store procedure you do not need to use `@vehicleName` this pattern which we use in `SQL`. You can [`check the official docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters) for how you can write the syntax accordingly here.  You should try like below:

```
string VehicleName = "Hatchback";
var sqlCommand = $"EXEC GetVehicleByTile {VehicleName}";
var vehicleFilterValues = await _context.VehicleFilter.FromSqlRaw(sqlCommand).ToListAsync();
```

**`Demo SQL Store Procedure:`**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetVehicleByTile]
(
    
    @VehicletFilterTitle nvarchar(150)
)
AS

BEGIN

    SELECT  VehicleFilterId, VehicleId, VehicleFilterName, VehicletFilterTitle
    FROM VehicleFilter
    WHERE VehicletFilterTitle = @VehicletFilterTitle

END

EXEC GetVehicleByTile 'Hatchback'
```

***`Controller:`***

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllFilter()
        {
            string VehicleName = "Hatchback";
            var sqlCommand = $"EXEC GetVehicleByTile {VehicleName}";
            var vehicleFilterValues = await _context.VehicleFilter.FromSqlRaw(sqlCommand).ToListAsync();
            return Ok(vehicleFilterValues);
        }
```

***`Final Output:`***

[image]

> ***`Note:`*** Make sure the column you have defined at your `DbSet<VehicleFilter>` is provided from the `store procedure`
> accordingly.Other than you might be above error.